# How to import a 3D mesh which is generated by Gmsh to Fipy?

Tags: python-2.7, mesh, fipy

I'm working on a coupled DEM-CFD model. I'm using Fipy for its CFD part and my geometry is cylinder. How can I import generated mesh in Gmsh to Fipy?

I need to generate a cylindrical geometry and discretised it by generating triangular mesh in 3D in Fipy. I tried to find a command in the help of Fipy to generate a 3D triangular mesh in cylindrical geometry, but I couldn’t find anything relevant for 3D. I have generated the Mesh in Gmsh software which is accepted by Fipy based on its help. I have the mesh file now, but I cannot import it to Fipy.

Whenever I tried to import it to the model, I faced with this error `Gmsh version must be >= 2.0`. However, my Gmsh version was 4.

I used Gmsh V2.5 as well but the error was the same. I searched the error and I see some people were struggling with that as well. They recommended to put the Gmsh.exe file in script folder to solve the problem. I have done that but I’ve got another error. The new error is

```
Windows Error: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

when the command was `mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh")`.

I searched this error as well and someone suggested to mention geometry file after mesh, `mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh, Cylinder.geo")`. 
Now, I’m getting this

```
GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code.
```

I tried to make the circular mesh which is a 2D triangular mesh in a circle (it is in Fipy help), but I got this

```
GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code
```

The python scritp, cylinder.msh, cylinder.geo and Gmsh.exe files are in the same folder.

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\jpethati\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 809, in read
    raise GmshException(errStr)

GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code.
```

Gmsh output:

```
Info    : Running 'gmsh c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmpsw2tzg.geo -3 -nopopup -format msh -o c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmp6gbww9.msh' [Gmsh 4.2.2, 1 node, max. 1 thread] 
Info    : Started on Fri Mar 29 10:25:25 2019 
Info    : Reading 'c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmpsw2tzg.geo'... 
Info    : Done reading 'c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmpsw2tzg.geo' 
Info    : Meshing 1D... 
Info    : Done meshing 1D (0 s) 
Info    : Meshing 2D...
Info    : Done meshing 2D (0 s) 
Info    : Meshing 3D... 
Info    : Done meshing 3D (0 s) 
Info    : 0 vertices 0 elements 
Info    : Writing 'c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmp6gbww9.msh'... 
Info    : Done writing 'c:\users\jpethati\appdata\local\temp\tmp6gbww9.msh' 
Info    : Stopped on Fri Mar 29 10:25:25 2019
```

```
import fipy as fp
```

First try

```
mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh")
```

Second try

```
mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh, Cylinder.geo")
```

Comment: Please try version 3.0.7 of Gmsh or older: http://gmsh.info/bin/Windows/. Gmsh 4 has broken some things for us and we haven't had time to figure it out, yet.

Comment: I couldn't find version 3.0.7. I used Gmsh version 3.0.6, 2.5.0, 2.7.0 and 2.11.0 but all of them gave me the same thing: GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 3.0.6. `mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh, Cylinder.geo")` is not valid syntax. You can try `mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.msh")` or `mesh = fp.Gmsh3D("Cylinder.geo")`.

Answer (score 0):

FiPy 3.3 resolved some issues with Gmsh on Windows. Please upgrade and let us know if you're still having problems.